# Rotate an image synchronously along a curve with jQuery.animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, curve

How does jQuery.animate() determine the number of "frames" that are necessary to perform its function?  I thought this ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9eXE/68/)) would perform 90 adjustments over the course of 2 seconds, but it ends up performing 150.

That makes it difficult to synchronize the angular rotation of the missile with the curve.  I want it at that speed or slower, yet slowing it down further only increases the rotational effect.  To see how it should appear (roughly), change **`duration: 2000`** to 1250.

Update: Inexplicably, the Fiddle only appears to work in Chrome (not Firefox). No idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use the `progress` callback function which jquery provides. See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/, and within that, use *only* the parameters it gives you;

```
$thing.animate({left:100},{progress:function(animation, progress, remaining){
    // do stuff with progress
}});
```

(Edited: sorry, progress not step)

Here is an update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9eXE/78/ (I actually am using step there, simply because it's easier to get the current *tweened* progress, and it makes no difference when you're only animating a single property)

Comment: This reply utterly confuses me. I'm using `step`. Are you saying I'm using it incorrectly?

Comment: Apologies; I edited it. Use progress. You don't need to know how many steps it takes in here, because you get a number which ranges from 0 to 1 as the animation completes. Just use that to interpolate your rotation

Comment: In other words, stop using your own variable i to keep track of rotation, and set it using t, like you're setting the position.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So: `var angle = -90 - t;` Thanks!

Comment: @daveycroqet essentially yes (though it would need some constants adding in). I went with a slightly different approach in the fiddle (using css transform instead of the rotate function, which is what jquery uses internally anyway)